# What could be causing selenium tests to run differently on a different machine?

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I'm using selenium and phantomjs to run automated tests. My tests run fine on my local machine. I need to run my tests on a windows server as part of a scheduled task that then emails the results each morning. When my tests are run on the server, a good majority fail and the screenshot that is taken upon failure is blank. Logs show it would appear its failing to load some pages when navigating from one page to another.

Comment: Your question is broad and opinion based.

Comment: I don't think this question is "opinion based", but it is broad: are you trying to investigate why screenshots are blank (although pages are not), or why pages are blank or why navigation fails? might be completely different issues.

Comment: i appoligize, the question is a bit broad. Unsure exactly whats happening. Basically all my tests run fine on one machine but on another machine some tests randomly fail. Both machines are set up with exactly the same dev enviroment. But, yes why would phantomjs be outputting blank screenshots when a test case fails?